# Sharing JS variables in multiple <script> blocks

Tags: javascript, ajax, codeigniter, variables

I'm working on a CodeIgniter application.

I have a view, let's call it Calendar, which has a JS/jQuery `<script>` block in it. Looks like this:

```
    $(document).ready(function()    {

        $("#day_list").fadeIn(600);

        // init
        var current_month = <?= $init['current_month']; ?>;
        var current_year = <?= $init['current_year'] ?>;

        // previous, next month ajax call
        $(".previous, .next").click(function(event) {
            // do stuff to these variables, then ajax call.
            $.ajax({
                // ajax
            });
        });
    });
```

In another view, my footer, I have another script block which should use the same variables (current_month and current_year). However, it doesn't know about their existence. What would be the quickest, and easiest, way to pass these variables from the first `<script>` block to the other? I can't put the two blocks together because of the way my application is build. Should I just write a function for it which gets and returns these values (and how should I do this? I'm such a newbie) or is there an easier way?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's really important to learn to namespace your variables in JavaScript. Scope matters, and it matters a lot. Right now because you're using the "var" keyword, your stuff will be in the local scope.

Some of the other answers here say that you should move them into the global scope. That works, unless something else overwrites them unintentionally. I highly disagree with this approach, globally scoped variables are bad practice in JavaScript.

Namespacing works like this:

```
var foo = foo || {} //Use existing foo or create an empty object.
foo.bar = foo.bar || {}
foo.bar.baz = foo.bar.baz || {}
```

etc. etc.

This may seem like a lot more work, but it also PROTECTS YOUR VARIABLES.

You can also add a simple namespacing function that safely namespaces everything against the window object. (I cribbed this from somewhere ages ago, and I think I modified it a little but maybe didn't).

Put this at the top of your app and you can namespace stuff with $.namespace("myapp.mydata") and then say myapp.mydata.currentYear = ...

```
$.namespace = function() {
    var a=arguments, o=null, i, j, d;
    for (i=0; i<a.length; i=i+1) {
        d=a[i].split(".");
        o=window;
        for (j=0; j<d.length; j=j+1) {
            o[d[j]]=o[d[j]] || {};
            o=o[d[j]];
        }
    }
    return o;
};
```

Also, if you're new, or want to get hardcore, I recommend reading JavaScript the Good Parts by Crockford.

Comment: Thanks. I'll definitely try this once I wrap my head around the concept. Thank you for recommending the book. I've been meaning to pick up a book but there are so many of them, haha. Thanks!

Comment: No prob. The Good Parts is considered by many to be the definitive book on the JavaScript language.

Answer (score 13):

Declare the variables as global. Just move them outside of the document ready function.

```
var current_month = <?= $init['current_month']; ?>;
var current_year = <?= $init['current_year'] ?>;

$(document).ready(function() {
....
});
```

`current_month` and `current_year` can now be accessed from any script block.

Comment: ah .... nice thanks. Also had to move it outside of the (function ($) { })(jQuery);  wrapper.

Answer (score 3):

If you declare your variables outside of any function block, they will be global variables, available to any script on the page.

```
var current_month;
var current_year;

$(document).ready(function () {

    // init
    current_month = <?= $init['current_month']; ?>;
    current_year = <?= $init['current_year'] ?>;

    ...etc...

});
```

Answer (score 2):

The "var" declaration initializes both variables (`current_month`, `current_year`) in the ready function scope - thus they are not available elsewhere. You can declare them globally:

```
var current_month;
var current_year;
$(document).ready(function()    {
    ...
    current_month = ...
}
```

That way you can use them in the bottom script.

Answer (score 1):

Since you var declared these variables inside of a function, they have local scope. Move them outside to make them global:

```
// init
var current_month = <?= $init['current_month']; ?>;
var current_year = <?= $init['current_year'] ?>;

$(document).ready(function()    {

    $("#day_list").fadeIn(600);

    // previous, next month ajax call
    $(".previous, .next").click(function(event) {
        // do stuff to these variables, then ajax call.
        $.ajax({
            // ajax
        });
    });
});
```

The better solution than having global variables is to store them semantically in your HTML, then retrieve them through jQuery:

```
<body data-month="<?= $init['current_month']; ?>" data-year="<?= $init['current_year'] ?>">

$(document).ready(function()    {
    $("#day_list").fadeIn(600);

    var current_month = $("body").data("month");
    var current_year = $("body").data("year");

    // previous, next month ajax call
    $(".previous, .next").click(function(event) {
        // do stuff to these variables, then ajax call.
        $.ajax({
            // ajax
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: A s front-end developer who is mainly a web stylist, it is always tempting to do this, to deposit your JS variables in the HTML for later retrieval, but is it *really* a good, maintainable solution?