# Building a Blog - JQuery dynamic post grabber

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, blogs

I'm building a Blog with Html/Css/JQuery and I've hit a wall.

I want to load a different Blog Post based on the Number passed in from the link beforehand. For example, if I have 3 Posts, load content based on which number is selected.

This is in `content.js`.

```
var prepareContent = function (postNumber) {
     readTextFile(postNumber);
};
```

However, I have no clue how to manipulate `postNumber` when `click` is called in another `.js` file.

This is in `index.js`.

```
$("#post0").click(function () {
    conentPassed = 0;
    window.location = "content.html";

});

$("#post1").click(function () {
    contentPassed = 1;
    window.location = "content.html";
});
```

I would like to "pass" a variable into `content.js` from `index.js`. Is there any way to do this? Thank you.

Comment: Similar questions: [JavaScript: Two separate scripts - share variables?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8348401/javascript-two-separate-scripts-share-variables) # [Global variables in Javascript across multiple files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2932782/global-variables-in-javascript-across-multiple-files) # [Sharing JS variables in multiple <script> blocks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5781197/sharing-js-variables-in-multiple-script-blocks) # [Pass variables between different .js files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17172634/pass-variables-between-different-js-files)

Comment: I looked at those questions and it only seems to work if I use both JQuery scripts in one Html file. Extending the question, is there any way to manipulate the variable if each script is attached to different Html files?

Comment: Use local or sesssion storage to store the variable and then call it from local / session  storage in each of the pages and pass it into the relevant functions

Comment: what are `$("#post0")` and `$("#post1")`? Sure looks like you are trying to reproduce `<a>` tags that would do what you need with less complication

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think as ThisClark has pointed out there are similar problem-solutions.

I had a similar problem a while back and found that a hash addition to the url helped:

```
window.location = "content.html/#" + contentPassed;
```

then on the receiving end:

```
postNumber = window.location.href.split("#")[1];
postNumber = Number(postNumber);
```

this gets the current url, then splits it into parts using the hash as the splitter, the parts become an array, and the [1] gets you the second part. The second line is to be sure it's no longer a string.

don't know if this helps?

Comment: I'll try it out! Thanks :).

Comment: forgot: your outgoing line should be window.location.href = "conte.... (add the href to go there)

Comment: Do you have any idea why my attached Resource files aren't loading properly when I load "content.html/#0"? It loads fine when it's simply "content.html"

Comment: seems your path for the resources is relying on the url, I didn't come across this problem, can only suggest fixing the resource file paths. however, if this isn't an option then perhaps this method is a no go? sorry. or can you tell me how your resources are referenced? do you mean scripts or image files (or both?)

Comment: It's my Scripts and StyleSheets giving me the error.

Comment: is the path to these scripts set by the url? consider using the query string method i.e. a `?` instead of a `#` . if you have images and they work then the try to ensure you're using the same path/src describing method for your scripts?

Comment: The path of these scripts are set in the Html file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123297/discussion-between-sam0-and-steven).

Comment: Got it to work. Used link as "content.html?post=0" and used that parameter. Thank you for setting me in right direction.